# Method to prove limit in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Given is the following limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}$.

Now, it holds that
$0\leq\left\vert\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}\right\vert\leq \frac{x^3y}{y^2}=\left\vert\frac{x^3}{y}\right\vert$.

It is clear that $(x,y)\mapsto\frac{x^3}{y}$ is homogeneous on $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{\vec0\}$. This implies that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3}{y}=0$.

The squeeze lemma would now imply that
$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}=0$.

Where does it go wrong?

Comment: On line 2, you probably forgot an absolute value and also to mention that $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$.

Comment: Another problem is that the equality $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3}{y}=0$ is false (consider the case $x=y^3$) ...

Comment: Adren, indeed I forgot the absolute value and mentioning that $(x,y)\neq\vec0$. But, if $x=y^3$, then $\frac{x^3}{y}=\frac{y^9}{y}=y^8\to0$.

Comment: You're right ! It's a typo : I meant $y=x^3$ ... If you consider the map defined on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^\times$ by $\phi(x,y)=\frac {x^3}y$, you can see that $\phi(x,x^3)=1$ for all $x\neq0$.

Comment: Adren, yes I see this. But I still do not get why the homogenousity argument is not working in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Using the AM-GM inequality, we have $x^4+y^2\ge 2\sqrt{x^4y^2}=2x^2|y|$.  Then, we have

$$\left|\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}\right|\le \frac12|x|\to 0$$

Comment: I did realise this later, but I used the homogeneous argument in my homework. My question is whether or not this was legitimate.

Comment: Well $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x^3/y$ fails to exist.  So the method in the OP unfortunately is flawed.

Comment: I know this by now. But where does it go wrong then in my reasoning? As I do rely on the theorem that homogeneous functions with $\alpha>0$ have limit zero. But, it must be the case then that I cannot resort to this theorem, but why?

Comment: Why do you believe that homogeneity of a rational function implies that it approaches $0$ at the origin?  It certainly does not, as exemplified here.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did not realise that the homogeneous function limit theorem only holds if it holds for all $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ that $f(rx,ry)=r^\alpha f(x,y)$. In my case, this does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\frac {|x^3y|}{x^4+y^2}.$ We have $x^2|y|\leq \frac {(x^2+|y|)^2}{4}$ so $$S=\frac {|x|\cdot x^2|y|}{x^4+y^2} \leq \frac {|x|(x^2+|y|)^2}{4(x^4+y^2)}=$$ $$=\frac {|x|(x^4+y^2)+2|x^3y|}{4(x^4+y^2)}=$$ $$ =\frac {|x|}{4}+\frac {S}{2}.$$  $$ \text {Therefore }\quad S\leq \frac {|x|}{2}.$$

Not as slick as the answer from Dr.MV but it works.