# Proving that $ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy^3}{x^2+2y^4} $ doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove that $ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy^3}{x^2+2y^4} $ doesn't exist. Every path I choose in real plane tends to 0. Is it possible to do it that way?

Comment: No reason for downvote, question is good worded and to the point.

Comment: @Mastrem the limit exists. Your paths are the straight lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ which OP has already tried.

Comment: [Method to prove limit in $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210289/method-to-prove-limit-in-mathbbr2) is the same question with the roles of $x,y$ switched. See if this answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM inequality

$$\frac{|xy^3|}{x^2+2y^4} \leq \frac{|xy^3|}{2\sqrt{2}|x|y^2} < |y|$$

Thus the limit exists and equals $0$ by squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Now I wonder why Wolfram Alpha gave the answer that this limit does not exist... Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Hela wolfram cannot do multivariable limits except in the simplest of cases of continuous functions.